# input width difference Ubuntu 18 GNOME Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-shell

Some solution to fix this difference without custom static width\height settings for inputs in css? I mean looks like it possible draw each input with custom static size, but need solution solution to equalize forms in both browsers.

Simple HTML code for both browsers:

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="text">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Feel the difference...
Left input - Firefox, right input - Google Chrome:

[image]

**Firefox:**
[image]

**Chrome:**
[image]

Comment: If you want to display same input style in every browser, then go to CSS and style yourself. Every browser has own rules for styling input

Comment: that would be why in many projects something like reset css or normalize css is used. it helps to bring different browser render closer together

Comment: You say you don't want a "custom static size", so what kind of solutions were you thinking of? Would a sizing in `em` or `ch` also be considered static?

Comment: In case different browsers renders must exist some reset.css